# DDD - model and enforce invariants for workflow engine

Tags: domain-driven-design, workflows, aggregate, invariants

I'm trying to design a workflow engine using a DDD approach.

##### Context

- *(B1) Assign items to a workflow*

  - Invariant: depending on their types, items can only start the workflow on specific steps.
- *(B2) Attach/detach items to other items*

  - Invariant: all items (container and elements) must be on the same step.
- *(B3) Transition items from one step to another*

  - Invariant 1: the transition should also be applied to their children.
  - Invariant 2: items inside a container can't be transitioned directly.

Clients may have several active workflows. They just know about items (or some VO representing an item). Everything should be done through a facade.

#### Preferred solution

So far, I designed it as a typical graph.

`Workflow (AR)` holds all steps. `Steps (entity)` contains the items & allowed transitions. `Items (entity)` knows its parent and its children.

**Pros & cons**

The consistency boundary looks ok. Even though I could be changing the same workflow on different transactions, as long as the items aren't the same everything should work.

B2 and B3 may have a race condition, but it might be ok they do as the invariants kind of depend on each other.

Usually, you work on one step at the time. So loading the whole workflow seems unnecessary. Also, I can't think of a *natural* way of loading it with the items in the correct steps.

This solution looks fine. However, **I feel something is missing**.

#### Another things I've thought about

- **Create a `Associations` AR**

  The Associations AR would have a reference to the parent item and a collection of children items. Here I could query the workflow and check if the items are in the same step to keep B2 invariant.

  However, this is a bit fragile as the entities could be transitioned on a different transaction and I'd not know it.
- **Step as AR**

As you usually work on one Step at a time, this could be a possible solution. However, B2 2nd invariant can't be 100% enforced. Also I'd need to raise an event to perform B3.

Any thoughts/opinions about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, enclosing Steps and Items within the Workflow aggregate results in a large aggregate structure but keeps the overall complexity low. Raising Events and backgrounding jobs is fine, but it is always better to enforce invariants upfront - it leads to less complexity.

The only connection between the Workflow entity and its children seems to be that you need to start the Workflow on specific items/steps (I may be reading your invariants wrong, let me know). As and when the complexity in the Step entity increases or you find that you are loading the workflow aggregate for no other reason than operating on a Step, you could elevate Step to be an aggregate as well.

This structure fits well with working with one Step at a time. You can start the Workflow with a background Event Handler that listens to events published by the Step Aggregate.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I agree the workflow aggregate may be too big. My biggest concern with **Step as AR** is that for transitioning items between Steps (and enforcing the invariants) I'd need to change 2 aggregates within the same transaction.

Comment: Maybe I'm trying to hard to adhere to the "single AR per transaction" rule?

Comment: Single AR per transaction is pretty invaluable, so your thought process is correct. When you say two aggregates, are you meaning two steps or a step and its associated workflow?

Comment: It may be good to go with a single Workflow aggregate, run with it for some time, and then elevate Step to be an aggregate only if you observe issues. You may discover that the Workflow aggregate is not as big as you thought, or you may be able to better clarify your apprehensions about having Step as an aggregate.

Comment: `are you meaning two steps or a step and its associated workflow?` I meant 2 steps. I could try to be a bit cleaner and use events like `TransitionIntendIssued` and `TransitionApplied`.

Comment: If dealing with two steps, yes, having an aggregate to govern them is the easiest and makes the most sense.

Comment: @Subhash Single AR per transaction is pretty invaluable *if* you foresee the need to shard your data between ARs. That seems very unlikely in this scenario. OP - the single AR per transaction "rule" is, without a doubt, the most cited reason systems undertake incredible amounts of unnecessary complexity. The above is just a *guideline* and only really applies in systems where a distributed transaction between ARs is likely to occur should boundaries be drawn. It's about scaling! Are you worried about scaling? Even if you are, there are *better* sharding strategies to consider (e.g. ID ranges).

Comment: To be clear, I'm not advocating for multiple ARs. Honestly I think your "Preferred Solution" with a single AR is probably the best way to organize your system. But don't hesitate to explore other designs solely because you think you may be eschewing the *guideline* above.

Comment: Amen to treating these "rules" as guidelines. Though this guideline is related to transactions, I have always considered it to be a measure of complexity. In the past when two aggregates need to be updated in the same transaction (I have done this a bunch of times), code complexity invariably increased over time because of the coupling.

Comment: @Subhash The coupling is inextricable. It does not matter how we model it. We are *doing* the same thing with the same data. Often trying to "avoid updating 2 ARs in a single transaction" creates **FAR** more complexity because you are trying to *decouple* two things that are logically coupled no matter what (see invariants above). You end up with all sort of cruft (additional domain objects, message queues, event systems, eventual consistency, etc.) in order to mediate a process that can *easily* be handled within a single transaction (i.e. w/o adding any code at all).

Comment: @Subhash I don't disagree with the "design smell" angle you are coming from. It can certainly be useful to identify and ruminate on the places in a system where may update 2 ARs at once, but the reality is that the world is messy and sometimes you need to "create a new AR" and "update an existing AR" at the same time (by far the most common case where the above occurs).

Comment: @king-side-slide We are on the same page. I understand the rationale and practice it too. All I am saying is to follow the guideline by default and only break it consciously.

Comment: Thanks both! I'll keep in mind these "rules" are more guidelines

Comment: @king-side-slide my biggest fear is trying to do B2 & B3 on the same items but in different transactions. My code will be distributed as a library and the clients, as owners of the DB, will be persisting the items.

Comment: In this context, I'm thinking of keeping the whole workflow graph in memory and let the clients persist an item DTO (with information of the node & workflow they are in).

Comment: Whenever they call the lib, I'd load the DTOs from DB (using repo interface) and transform them into item entities. Then, I'd clone the graph, inject the items in the proper node and perform the requested actions. Finally, the "save workflow" will actually save the DTOs. Am I overcomplicating things here?

Comment: I see. You are worried about concurrency (more specifically version control but I digress...). The high-level strategy is to validate the inputs "server-side" before persisting any data. We can either validate using our "database": locking can provide a guarantee that the data sent to the client matches the data held in the server for the lifetime of the transaction (https://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=83).

Comment: Or we can validate on our "server": Commonly a `Version` parameter is used to mediate the process. Fit the above to your use-case (I'm aware the strategy you are describing above is a bit different, but my use of quotes is intentional).

Comment: Yes, we are thinking of using optimistic locking for those DTOs. That way B2 and B3 shouldn't be able to change the same items. I just wanted to check if there was a way to enforce this by finding the correct model. Thanks!